# How to get a fixed value of random function?

Tags: python, random

I am trying to get the number of common elements from two randomly-selected list as you can see in the code at the bottom of this post.

A problem is that

```
print(count_matching_numbers(generate_numbers(), draw_winning_numbers()))
```

the result of the above print function is based on which def. functions inside the print one independently generate output, not from

```
def generate_numbers():
    result = random.sample(range(1, 46), 6)
    result.sort()
    return result
```

or

```
def draw_winning_numbers():
    win = generate_numbers()
    for i in win:
        bonus = random.randint(1, 45)
        bonus not in win
    win.append(bonus)
    return win
```

In a nutshell, I would like get a fixed output of random function.
What should I do to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance!

---

```
import random

def generate_numbers():
    result = random.sample(range(1, 46), 6)
    result.sort()
    return result

def draw_winning_numbers():
    win = generate_numbers()
    for i in win:
        bonus = random.randint(1, 45)
        bonus not in win
    win.append(bonus)
    return win

def count_matching_numbers(list1, list2):
    return len(set(list1) & set(list2))


print(generate_numbers())
print(draw_winning_numbers())
print(count_matching_numbers(generate_numbers(), draw_winning_numbers()))
```

Comment: you could a) hard code the value, or b) set the random seed

Comment: @PaulH: or c) use `unittest.mock()` and patch `sample` and `randint` to return pre-determined numbers. Not as straightforward as setting the seed though.

Comment: But most of all, the OP should not call the functions twice. Use variables instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that inside the three `print`, the function will call independently. You could assign the function result to some variable, then pass the variable to the last function like this:

```
import random

def generate_numbers():
    result = random.sample(range(1, 46), 6)
    result.sort()
    return result

def draw_winning_numbers():
    win = generate_numbers()
    for i in win:
        bonus = random.randint(1, 45)
        bonus not in win
    win.append(bonus)
    return win

def count_matching_numbers(list1, list2):
    return set(list1) & set(list2)

from_generate = generate_numbers() # call function only once
from_draw_winning = draw_winning_numbers() # call function only once

print(from_generate)
print(from_draw_winning)
print(count_matching_numbers(from_generate, from_draw_winning))
```

Output will be:

```
[3, 16, 23, 24, 34, 35]
[3, 11, 22, 23, 34, 39, 36]
set([34, 3, 23])
```